# grep line from text file including brackets

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have a file called a.txt

```
something [low] https://url/low.txt
something [info] http://url1/low.txt
something [low] https://url2/robots.txt
```

How can i achieve this output using grep command?

```
something [low] https://url/low.txt
something [low] https://url2/robots.txt
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
grep 'something \[low\]' a.txt
```

The single quotes are to prevent the shell from interpreting the brackets (and breaking on the space).
`grep` itself uses brackets for simple regular expressions, so the brackets need to be escaped separately, inside the single quotes, to not have grep interpret them as special.

Using `grep -F` or `fgrep` doesn't use regular expressions: everything to grep on is taken as a single string pattern. The single quotes would still be necessary to prevent the shell from interpreting the brackets specially.

Comment: using `-F` is another option